# Тире в сочетании с вопросом

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, тире, вопрос

> Когда? – В понедельник.

1. Можно ли так (сочетание знаков) писать?
2. Если нет, то:
   • Убираем знак вопроса – проблема у читателя c пониманием, что это вопрос (в принципе, может не конкретно в моём продолжении. Да и грамотно ли писать вопрос без знака?).
   • Если тире убрать, то помеха для понимания что там ответ (опять же в принципе!) – может повествование продолжается и вообще с этим вопросом едва связано.
   • Неужели читатели остаётся ориентироваться по смыслу предложений?

Answer (score 1):

Это прямая речь, точнее диалог.

> #### Знаки препинания при диалоге
>
> 2. Если реплики следуют в подбор без указания, кому они принадлежат, то каждая из них заключается в кавычки и отделяется от соседней посредством тире

[(Розенталь, § 123)](http://rosental-book.ru/punct_xxxi.html#sect123)

Так что, правильная постановка знаков препинания в вашем случае такая:

> «Когда?» — «В понедельник».